# Discrete Gibbs free energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability, information

Is it possible to define discrete (informational) Gibbs free energy
by analogy with Shannon entropy?

This is about cellular automata, in particular [on a network](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227998/how-to-simulate-a-cellular-automaton-on-a-network).
We can easily calculate entropy of their states using Shannon's formula.
I'm interested is it possible to calculate somehow Gibbs free energy?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but can you give more details about your background and exactly what you want to know? It would be a rather long answer otherwise.

Comment: @Nathaniel, it's done